Why border width is different from what i set it to be?
When box-sizing is set to content-box(default) why border size is little less than what i set it to be? i set border size to 10px but in box model it shows 9.600px.
does anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve this?
Any help would be appreciated.
CSS
div{
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    #div1{
      background-color: cadetblue;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 10px solid black;
      
    }
    

HTML
<div id="div1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at sapien porttitor urna elementum lacinia. In
      id magna pulvinar, ultricies lorem id, vehicula elit. Aliquam eu luctus nisl, vitae pellentesque magna. Phasellus
      dolor metus, laoreet ac convallis sit amet, efficitur sed dolor.</p>
  </div>

Things i have tried

My browser is set to 100% zoom.
I have tried other browsers too but nothing worked.
I know border-box can solve this problem but right now i am trying this exercise on default.

Here is the image of result

Is your browser set to 100% zoom? Other zoom settings could cause that.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

i would love to answer it ! in your case, you set the border size to 10px. However , with content-box, the browser calculates the available space for the border by subtracting the padding from the declared width. There might be some slight browser-specific rounding or anti-aliasing involved, which could explain the slight difference from an even 10px.
Example:
consider an element with:
width :100px
padding :2px
border: 10px solid black
with content-box:
*Available space for border: width-padding = 100px -2px = 98px
*Due to rounding or anti-aliasing, you might see a slightly smaller border size, like 9.600px.
Solution
To ensure the border exactly matches your desired size (10px in this c ase), you can use box-sizing: border-box:
box-sizing:border-box;
width:100px;
padding:2px;
border:10px solid black;

with border-box , the padding and borde are included within the declared width and height, so the final size will be exactly 100px (width) + 10px (border on each side) = 120px.

but i don't want to use border-box . by the way i have tried border-box too but it doesn't work either although i tried it on another program but i was having the same problem there. here you can check the screenshot i have added it now.

Your explanation of border-box seems to be inconsistent. Is the border width included within the set width (as you initially claim) or not (as your arithmetic shows). Best not to rely on AI to answer this type of question.
